# viewport of browser from cross-site iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

I need to find out the browser viewport size from within a cross-domain iframe. The [normal method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860524/javascript-how-to-find-out-width-and-height-of-viewpoint-in-browser-window/1860596#1860596) doesn't work because it only gets the viewport of the iframe. If I use `top.innerHeight`, etc. in a cross-domain situation, I run into security issues. Is there a different property/method I can use? Cross-browser would be ideal, but even getting this on a single browser would be helpful.

(I'm trying to find out if my iframe is in view or not.)

Comment: This (knowing whether an iFrame is in view or not) has been discussed once, but I can't find the duplicate. IIRC, the conclusion back then was that it is not possible.

Comment: Related/somewhat similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860931/what-optimizations-does-a-browser-perform-when-a-dom-element-is-being-rendered-of

Comment: thanks. hmm... yeah, I was afraid of that...