# Can I tell what browser-chrome elements are visible in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

By "browser-chrome elements", I mean things like the status bar, bookmarks bar, etc. I see properties like `window.statusbar.visible`, but it seems to be `true` whether or not I show it, at least according to firebug. Am I missing something?

(Note: ultimately, I need to be able to get this info from a cross-site iframe for it to be useful to me, but even with a top-level script, I'm seeing this.)

Comment: What purpose would knowing if the user's statusbar is visible serve?

Comment: it's not just the status bar, it's all the chrome, but it would help determine the viewport dimensions in a situation where I can get the outer dimensions of the window, but not the inner ones. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869000/viewport-of-browser-from-cross-site-iframe

Comment: but also, I just find it odd that window.statusbar.visible is always true, so I'm curious.

Comment: What are your javascript execution settings? http://imgur.com/rb9dr

Comment: same as in that screen shot. (the default, I assume.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.statusbar.visible` and related properties only tell you whether your popup window was opened with or without the `statusbar` chrome flag, and even then, that requires the `dom.disable_window_open_feature.status` preference to be turned off. My understanding is that the "pill" on the Mac that toggles all the toolbars also affects this flag. Other ways of hiding chrome (e.g. via View - Show/Hide - Status Bar) cannot be detected by web pages.